# Axler exercise 2.C.1: vector spaces with only one basis

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to solve (for self-study) exercise 2.C.1 in Axler's book, which states:

> Find all vector spaces that have exactly one basis.

Axler takes the ground field to be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ in this book, but there are edge cases involving finite fields that I want to explore for a more complete solution. Here is what I have so far.

So when $V = \{0\}$, there is exactly one basis, the empty set. So the trivial subspace will always work, regardless of the ground field.

Say that $V$ is one-dimensional, i.e., $V = \text{span}(w)$ ($w \neq 0$). Provided that the ground field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, then any non-zero multiple of $w$ is also a basis for $V$. In fact, any non-zero vector would suffice as a basis for $V$, so $V$ lacks a unique.

A problem arises when I take $V$ to be a field over $\mathbb{Z}/2$. In fact, say $V = \mathbb{Z}/2$ itself with its usual addition and scalar multiplication as its usual multiplication. $\mathbb{Z}/2$ has only one non-zero element $\overline{1}$ and hence a unique basis. In $\mathbb{Z}/3$, I think $\overline{1}$ is likewise the only basis, but either $\overline{1}$ or $\overline{2}$ work for $\mathbb{Z}/4$. I'm getting the sense from trying example that $\mathbb{Z}/n$ for prime $n$ has only one basis, namely $\overline{1}$. Is there any truth to this intuition?

For two-dimensional vector spaces, I don't think any exist. If I take $V = (\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$, for example, I have a basis $(\overline{1}, \overline{0}), (\overline{0}, \overline{1})$ but also $(\overline{1}, \overline{1}), (\overline{1}, \overline{0})$.

I'd appreciate any help on working this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any nonzero vector $u$ can be mapped to any nonzero $u' \ne u$ by an invertible linear map*. The image of a basis $B$ under an invertible linear map is another basis. So if there is any nonzero vector $u$ not in the basis, there is a linear map mapping it to $u'$ not in the basis. This makes another basis $B' \ne B$. So the basis has to contain every nonzero element of the vector space.

If $u,v$ are in the basis, then $u+v$ is not in the basis, and is nonzero. So the basis must have less than $2$ elements. If $F \ne \mathbb{Z}_2$ you can just take an element $\lambda$ other than $0$ or $1$ and if $u$ is in the basis, $\lambda u$ isn't, and is nonzero. So the dimension must be less than $1$.

So the only cases are dimension $1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and dimension $0$ over anything.

---

*take a basis $B$ containing $u$, and a basis $B'$ containing $u' \ne u$ then map the first vector of $B$ to the first vector of $B'$, etc.

Comment: Please search for duplicates befor answering.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. If a basis for a vector space contains elements $v$ and $w$, then replacing $v$ with $v+w$ will also give an basis for this vector space (why?). If you can show that this basis is well-defined and is distinct from the original basis, you'll have proven that all vector spaces with dimension greater than $1$ have multiple bases.

For one-dimensional vector spaces, try showing that any nonzero element provides a basis for the space. What does that tell you about uniqueness?

Comment: Please search for duplicates befor answering.